# Scrapy is Visiting same Url despite dont_filter=False

Tags: python, scrapy

**Problem:** Scrapy keeps visiting a single url and keeps scraping it recursively. I have checked the response.url to ensure that this is a single page that it keeps scraping and there is no query string involved that may render the same page for different url.

**What I have done to reolve it :**

1. Under Scrapy/spider.py I noticed that dont_filter was set to True and changed it False. but it didn't help
2. I have set the unique = True also in the code, but this didn't help either.

**Additional information**

The Page thats given as start_url has only 1 link to a page a.html. Scrapy keeps scraping a.html again and again.

Code

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from kt.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["datacaredubai.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.datacaredubai.com/aj/link.html"]
    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/aj'),unique=('Yes')), callback='parse_item'), 
    )


def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//*') 
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = DmozItem()
        item['title']= site.xpath('/html/head/meta[3]').extract()         
        item['req_url']= response.url            
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: How do you run the spider and what are the settings you have? What scrapy version are you using? Thanks.

Comment: FYI, I cannot reproduce the problem - I see the URL visited only once.

Comment: Dear Alecxe, I am using scrapy 0.24.4.  I used the command "scrapy scrawl dmoz -t csv - o output.csv". its strange that you can see url visited only once, Could there be something wrong with my settings.py ?

Comment: My seetings.py has the following settings. Sorry I just hit enter last time in commend and it posted the comment. ' BOT_NAME = 'kt'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['kt.spiders']

NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'kt.spiders'

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 2

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1'

Comment: Strange, what code exactly your dmoz spider contains? Is it **exactly** the same as in the question?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. You think it may help if I reinstall scrapy. Some other setting somewhere may have been changed

Comment: Try removing the `pyc` files first and run the spider again. Also, how do you know it crawls the same URL multiple times?

Comment: - I removed all .pyc files and ran it again, the same problem. Reinstalled it also ( apt-get remove, and then apt-get install) but doesn't work still. I know same url is visited because I can see the same url in the response.url field of my csv, and all the fields are duplicated.

Comment: I created a blank scrapy project and insert your code. It's crawling only 2 urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy, by default, would **append** into the output file if it exists. What you see in the `output.csv` is the results of multiple spider runs. Remove the `output.csv` before running the spider again.

Comment: Yes I realize that the output is appended. I tried with fresh files and also with different non existing file names, but the same thing. Thank you for spending time on this problem. Would it help if I sent the spider directory zip ? probably there is something in my settings.py or items.py ?

Comment: @AkashJain thanks, yup, share your project (for example, upload on github). I'll take a look.

Comment: Hello Alecxe, thank you. I found out where I went wrong. I shouldn't have the for loop, its going over the same stuff again. I am just learning this stuff and simply plugged in some xpaths in example scrapy code.